# Avoiding creation of strings in contenteditable area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this pludgin: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/ to improve my contenteditable area, and stuff like this to populate it when clicking on a link:

```
$("#input-content").html(content);
```

The problem is that sometimes when the cursor is at the beginning of the div it creates strings like this:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid them? Via jQuery or something?

Comment: Can you possibly show a working example of the issue on jsfiddle.net or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for any text nodes `(nodeType === 3)` then wrap those nodes with the appropriate HTML tag as such:

> `function wrapText(){ 
>       $('#yourDiv').contents().filter(
>           function(){
>               return this.nodeType === 3;
>           }).wrap('<p/>');
>
>   }`

Then call `wrapText` on `blur`.

Comment: Thanks. So nodeType === 3 are elements surrounded by double quotes (text)?

Comment: The double quotes are there because the text nodes are objects of type `string`. The quotes are not part of the value that is rendered in the page - if you were to type quotes, you would see `""some text""` in the DOM inspector.